# Nuxt.JS doesen't render blocks as I need

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm building nuxt.js SSR web app and I face strange issue.

```
<div class="container" @mouseenter="hovered = true" @mouseleave="hovered = false">
  <transition name="fade">
    <div class="class1" v-show="!hovered && isDesktop">blank_1</div>
  </transition>
  <transition name='scale'>
    <div class="class2" v-show="hovered || !isDesktop">blank_2</div>
   </transition>
</div>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      hovered: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    isDesktop() {
      if(process.client) {             
        window.screen.width > 1024 ? return true : return false
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
.class1 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
.class2 {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
</style>
```

I'll explain this by few steps.

1. Let me explain how it should work:

   - Div with class="class1" should be displayed by default on Desktop and dissapear when you hover container. On mobile it should be hidden everytime.
   - Div with class="class2" should be hidden on Desktop and appear when you hover container. On mobile it should be displayed everytime.
2. Let me explain how it works now:

   1. Desktop:

      - Div with class="class1" **not displayed untill I hover container once, then works as it should**
      - Div with class="class2" works as it should.
   2. Mobile:

      - Div with class="class1" works as it should.
      - Div with class="class2" works as it should.
3. How did I fix it:

   - After few hours of trying I just realised that I can rewrite v-show on first div to  `v-show="!hovered"` and set media query on mobile screen `display:none;`. So I fixed the only Desktop issue that I have.

But why does it works this way when I have `v-show="!hovered && isDesktop"`?
I guessed that first load on Nuxt.JS goes on server, so **isDesktop** is returned as **undefined** so `v-show="!hovered && isDesktop"` turns into `v-show="!false && undefined"`. But then why second div's v-show directive: `v-show="hovered || !isDesktop"` works fine if it should turn into `v-show="false || !undefined"` but I still got this div **hidden on Desktop** and **displayed on Mobile**.

P.S. This is my first StackOverflow question, sorry if I styled code badly, I dont get how it works. Thank you for answers.

Comment: While it's not directly related to the problem, `isDesktop()` currently implicitly returns `undefined` when `process.client` is not true, it would be clearer to explicitly return `false`.

Answer (score 1):

The weird behavior probably comes from this line

```
window.screen.width > 1024 ? return true : return false
```

when it should be

```
return window.screen.width > 1024 ? true : false
```

The syntax is incorrect. Nuxt won't even compile it when i tried. I wonder why your Nuxt server can work with this.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but Im actually using `vuex` instead of `computed returns` and then I get the value of `isDesktop` variable via `vuex getter`. So your answer won't solve the problem. In issue description I just simplify the code to make it more clear to see what happens.